# Reduce and generalize a list of string

Tags: code-golf, string

The goal of this challenge is to reduce a list of string to a shorter more general list of string.

## Input

The Input is provided with space between the string (a b c) or in list form (["a","b", "c"]). It's a list list of string that can be of the following form :

- aaa
- aaaX
- aaaX/Y

With **aaa** any set of non capital alphabetic letter, and **X** or **Y** any digit between 0 and 9.

## Ouput

A list of generalized string that can be separated by anything. String are of the form :

- aaa
- aaaX
- aaaX/Y

With **aaa** any set of non capital alphabetic letter that were in the input list. X and Y stay the same and symbolise the digit. The goal of the challenge is to reduce the input list of string into their generic representation.

## Examples

Two strings can be reduced :

```
Input : regex1 regex2 split1/0
Output : regexX splitX/Y
```

Full example :

```
Input : toto toto titi titi1 titi2 titi5 tutu tutu0 tutu1 tutu1/2 tutu0/1
Output : toto titi titiX tutu tutuX tutuX/Y
```

Another example :

```
Input: ["foo0","bar0","baz0/0","eth0/0","eth0/1","eth1/0","eth1/1","vlan8","modem0"]

Output: ["fooX","barX","bazX/Y","ethX/Y","vlanX","modemX"]
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf; shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we take array of strings input, i.e. `["regex1","regex2","split1/0"]`?

Comment: I'll modify the question a bit to allow it =)

Comment: You may want to put the last line [elsewhere](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8387/48934), at least not in the scoring section

Comment: It's still in the scoring section...

Comment: Is extra trailing newlines okay?

Comment: The output can be as dirty as you want, it just have to separate value with something.

Comment: Alright, noted.

Comment: Is `foo1bar2` a possible input?

Comment: No, it's always a slash before the second digit if there is one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>25</s> <s>18</s> 13 bytes

**6 byte thanks to FryAmTheEggman, and for inspiration of extra 1 byte.**

```
\d
X
/X
/Y
D`
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQKWAovWAovWQpEYA&input=dG90bwp0b3RvCnRpdGkKdGl0aTEKdGl0aTIKdGl0aTUKdHV0dQp0dXR1MAp0dXR1MQp0dXR1MS8yCnR1dHUwLzE)

Comment: Wow, Upvoted because 120 seconds to answer is so impressive !

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas This site has seen faster answers.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input list as seperate lines on STDIN:

```
perl reduce.pl
regex1
regex2
split1/0
^D
```

reduce.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/\d/X/&&s//Y/;$_ x=!$$_++
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>61</s> <s>59</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

**2 bytes thanks to Fatalize.**

```
:{:ef:{~s"0123456789","X".;?.}ac.}a:{rbh"/",?rbr:"Y"c.;?.}ad.
:{:ef:{~s"0123456789","X".;?.}ac.L(rbh"/",Lrbr:"Y"c.;.)}ad.
:{s"/",?rbbbr:"X/Y"c.;.?t~s@A;?rbr:"X"c.}ad.
:{s"/",?rbbbr:"X/Y"c.|.t~s@A|rbr:"X"c.}ad.
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OntzIi8iLD9yYmJicjoiWC9ZImMufC50fnNAQXxyYnI6IlgiYy59YWQu&input=WyJ0b3RvIjoidG90byI6InRpdGkiOiJ0aXRpMSI6InRpdGkyIjoidGl0aTUiOiJ0dXR1IjoidHV0dTAiOiJ0dXR1MSI6InR1dHUxLzIiOiJ0dXR1MC8xIl0&args=Wg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
∪'/\d' '\d'⎕R'/Y' 'X'
```

`⎕R` regex replaces the left-side strings with the right-side ones

`∪` returns the unique elements

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u222A%27/%5Cd%27%20%27%5Cd%27%u2395R%27/Y%27%20%27X%27%20%u22C4%20f%27regex1%27%20%27regex2%27%20%27split1/0%27%20%u22C4%20f%27toto%27%20%27toto%27%20%27titi%27%20%27titi1%27%20%27titi2%27%20%27titi5%27%20%27tutu%27%20%27tutu0%27%20%27tutu1%27%20%27tutu1/2%27%20%27tutu0/1%27%20%u22C4%20f%27foo0%27%20%27bar0%27%20%27baz0/0%27%20%27eth0/0%27%20%27eth0/1%27%20%27eth1/0%27%20%27eth1/1%27%20%27vlan8%27%20%27modem0%27&run)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 69 bytes

```
import re
lambda s:set(re.sub("\d","X",s).replace("/X","/Y").split())
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>92</s> 78 bytes

```
a=a=>[...new Set(a.replace(/\d/g,"X").replace(/\/./g,"/Y").split` `)].join` `;
```

Comment: Oh whoops... I'll go fix that

Comment: You don't need a bunch of that boilerplate, just write this as `a=>[...new Set(a.replace(/[0-9]/g,"X").replace(/\/./g,"/Y").split\` \`)].join\` \``. Also why not use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`?

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, JSfiddle didn't like it. I'll try it on babel.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 104 bytes

```
<?=join(' ',array_unique(explode(' ',preg_replace('%\d%','X',preg_replace('%\d/\d%', 'X/Y',$argv[1])))))
```

expects input as single argument

I could replace the `join(' ',array_unique(explode(' ',...)))` with `preg_replace('%(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)%','',...)`, but it´s 6 bytes shorter via the array.

**127 bytes for list of arguments:**

```
<?foreach($argv as$i=>$s)if($i)$r[]=preg_replace('%\d%','X',preg_replace('%\d/\d%', 'X/Y',$s));echo join(' ',array_unique($r));
```

**120 bytes for a function on an array:**

```
function r($a){foreach($a as$s)$r[]=preg_replace('%\d%','X',preg_replace('%\d/\d%', 'X/Y',$s));return array_unique($r);}
```